# how to get json from describe feature type

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

i m using geoserver 2.1.3 i want to get the fields of layer from database 
http://[localhost]/geoserver/wfs?request=describeFeatureType&typename=topp:states
this reurns me output in xml format how can i get it in json

Answer (score 2):

The following request should work:

```
http://[hostname]/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=json
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution  to move from `XML` to `JSON` to use the yahoo YQL API. To familiarize you can use the YQL console (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console), and try a query like:

`select * from xml where url = 'your xml describeFeatureType request'`

and specify `json` as response format.

Note this YQL is particularly useful when you need to query xml data from Javascript and for which servers will reject xml request for security reasons. I personnally use this approach to query metadata xml files from OGC metadata catalogues.

Answer (score 0):

The output formats listed in the documentation is for WFS GetFeature requests. Not for DescribeFeatureType.

If you look at

http://[localhost]/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

you can read that the DescribeFeatureType operation only supports the outputFormat

```
text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
```

It's the same in newer versions of GeoServer as well. There are tools that can help you convert XML to JSON in almost every platform.

Comment: Hi! Any suggestions to how convert this http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Numeri_Civici_2012.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&bbox=7.59,44.83,7.75,44.94&outputFormat=GML2 in a JSON? Unfortunately this WFS service does not support json directly ... I need to use it in a Leaflet map. Thank you very much in advance! Cesare

Comment: @Cesare It's best to ask it as a question instead of in the comments.